# If you queue with a player in a lower SR, do you lose more SR points if you lose?

Tags: overwatch

If you queue with a player in a lower SR, do you lose more SR points if you lose?
and gain less SR points if you win? due to the fact that you are playing in a lower rank.

Comment: Not really - and numbers are also skewed for the first week of the season. You gain more SR than normal per win (upwards of 30+) and don't lose more than about 15 usually.

Comment: Not posting an answer since I'm not 100% sure, but if it's anything like League's ranking system, you and your partner's MMR/SR is averaged, and then you will gain rank based on the average rank of your team. So theoretically, the person with more SR would gain a little less than they normally would, and the person with less SR would gain a little more. I think per match both players earn the same total amount though.

Comment: @MageXy It does the same thing as LoL you're right, you get averaged when finding games (and there's a limited range you can team up in), but as OP is asking, I don't believe that the actual SR earned changes, as far as I have seen playing at least.

Comment: The SR you earn or lose is also affected by win\loss streaks so that will cause differences between your team members. I'm pretty sure Blizzard haven't officially said how SR works so it's a bit of a guess work how the differences between team members work out.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Unless you're part of the [Brazizlian 6 stack](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20753199103) the game will be able to find a suitable match with a similar SR to your party sooner rather than later.

As far as the game is concerned you're all evenly matched and the SR you win/loose will be the same regardless of weather you're 500 SR above your friend, 500 bellow, or solo-queuing.

Comment: Of course, the Season 4 changes were made in part to counter the Brazillian 6 stack.  See [this post](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20753625906), particularly the part near the bolded "we're not going to compromise as much anymore"